# Apache urlrewrite language specific

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a website with 2 languages, german and english.
The URL Rewrite i have working by now is:

```
RewriteRule ^(de|en)/(.*)$  index.php?lang=$1&content=$2 [L,QSA]
```

The lang parameter defines language, the content parameter - right, the content.
What i want now is, if someone comes to my site with www.example.com ($URL), it should be redirected to $URL/en/.
Also if someone comes with an language other then de or en ($URL/cz/) -> redirect to $URL/en/

How should the second rule look?

UPDATE:

I have now:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(de|en)/(.*)$  index.php?lang=$1&content=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^lang=(de|en)
RewriteRule (.*) /en/ [R=301,L]
```

That should do the trick, but my css/js/etc. sources get affected by that conditions too now. `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` and `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` seems to have no effect.

UPDATE2:
Juhu!
After the first Condition/Rule set, the conditions for files and directories have to be set again, thats the code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(de|en)/(.*)$  index.php?lang=$1&content=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^lang=(de|en)
RewriteRule (.*) /en/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: If the requested address is `www.example.com/go/something`, do you want it redirected to `www.example.com/en/go/something` (because if there is no language, it should switch to English) or to  `www.example.com/en/something` (because language `go` is neither English nor German, so it should be replaced with English?

Comment: Hy, thx for answer, `example.com/go/something` should become `example.com/en/something`